# How to use NServiceBus with MSMQ

Tags: nservicebus, msmq

I am experimenting the new version of NServicsBus. I find following step by step sample on particular site.
https://docs.particular.net/samples/step-by-step/

Can any one tell me how to configure MSMQ for Transport. Here is my scenario.

1. Client create message
2. Client message should be stored in MSMQ
3. Server Application running on same machine which subscribe the message.
4. Server handler get message from MSMQ and process it further. i.e Store in DB or send to other web service.
5. Retry to process message if it does not worked first time
6. after 3 retries send message to error queue

How do i configure this sample to use MSMQ for my scenario.

Helpful information to include
Product name:NServiceBus.Core
Version: 6.3.4
Stacktrace:
Description:

Comment: are you looking for 'endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();'?

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that we have released a `LearningTransport` and `LearningPersistence` just for purposes like these? Have a look at it [here](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/learning-transport/).

Having said that, the transport swapping should be rather seamless so even if you have setup a small PoC using this transport/persistence, you can change it to MSMQ or other production-ready transports/persistence when you go live.

Again, as stated in the documentation page and as the name suggests, this is not for use in production.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you walk through this.

https://docs.particular.net/tutorials/intro-to-nservicebus/

Will answer your questions, and future ones you have.

Comment: Thanks a lot. tutorial seems like answer all my questions. i ll go through it and write back here if i have any more questions.